# JS Signature issue in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, internet-explorer-9

I am new ho HTML 5. I am using Js Signature tool . I am keep getting error like this

```
Canvas element does not support 2d context. jSignature cannot proceed.
```

Only in Ie9. It works with all other IE version and other browsers.

Comment: did you include the `if IE9` check written about in this page? http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/about/

Comment: I have included. That's the reason error is coming. jSignature is always depends on flash JS. That is the problem.